OpenLayers intersectsExtent returning extents that do not intersect
When the user clicks on a feature, I need to show them all the lots that are inside that feature. Currently, the way I'm doing that is to use OpenLayers' intersectsExtent to find out which lots (from their geometry's extent) are inside the feature. However, for more complex geometries such as the one highlighted in red in the image below, OpenLayers is returning lots that are outside the geometry (in this example, it is returning the lot 0190, which I highlighted in the image below with a cyan arrow and is clearly outside the feature highlighted in red).
Is this a limitation of OpenLayers for geometries that are too complex (polygons with many sides) or am I doing something wrong?
    const lotesSource = lotesLayer.getSource() as VectorSource;
    const featureCroqui = lotesSource.getFeatures();
    const featureSelectedCroqui = featureSelected?.clone() as Feature<Geometry>;
    const geometry = featureSelectedCroqui.getGeometry();

    if (featureCroqui) {
      const lotes = featureCroqui.filter((lote) => {
        const loteGeometry = lote.getGeometry();
        return (
          loteGeometry &&
          geometry &&
          geometry?.intersectsExtent(loteGeometry.getExtent())
        );
      });

    }



Have a look at the definition of geometry extent: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_extent.html#~Extent

Please do not include a solution to your question in that question. Instead post it as an self-answer.

OpenLayers does not have an intersect function. It can only intersect against an extent. You need an additional library for that, e.g. turf: https://turfjs.org/

Thank you for the suggestion! You're correct—OpenLayers can only intersect extents. Using Turf.js for geometry intersections is an excellent approach.

An extent object is a minimum bounding box(or envelope) which is aligned to the coordinate grid. This means you're passing the minx, miny, Maxx, maxy as params. Knowing this it should be obvious why a shape like the example has an extent which  interests shapes beyond the boundary of your selecting polygon. You must pass the coordinates of the polygon to openlayers, not the extent.
